# Using bootstrap layout and there is extra unnecessary space on right side

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap layout there is extra space on the right side of the pages here's the [link](http://wishindia.in/wishindia/)
and please don't ask me for codes because i have tried to include codes here but it shows error all the time and i'm very frustrated with this.

Comment: You need to include the code in your question, and not as an external link. That is one of my reasons for downvoting your question.

Comment: I have tried so many times to include but it's showing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on the class name `container-fluid`.

**Before:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fulid">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
```

**After:**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
```

Please let me know if you face any issues with thix fix.

Comment: thanks.. but problem not completely solved now header got some issues please give me some solution for this also.

Comment: @Manish You need to set `padding:0px` to all the `col-sm-12` inside the `rows` under `container-fluid`, the default padding is causing this issue!